# naming: mipsle vs mipsel

Tags: architecture, mips

According to [this article](http://www.xinotes.net/notes/note/1657/), `mipsel` refers to little-endian MIPS. The word `mipsel` is currently used by [Debian](https://www.debian.org/ports/mips/) and [linux-mips wiki](https://www.linux-mips.org/wiki/Endianess).

However, [Golang refers to the same architecture(I guess) with `GOARCH=mipsle`](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/ad366fdbe40eea7f4fbdc75e8a27304c696793f1). So I was wondering is there any difference between `mipsle` and `mipsel`? Which one is a better choice?

Comment: I think `el` and `eb` is more common, like armel, mipsel, ppc64el... However Clang uses [ppc64le](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39114754/995714)